# Issue with transitioning between activities containing adapters sharing the same data set

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

Given 2 activities, A starts B for result.

Both activities have structures (A: RecyclerView, B: ViewPager) and adapters which connect to the same data set, stored in the Application object.

B finishes and posts the result back to A.

A gets the result on onActivityResult() and in the body of the function alters the data set (removes one element).

Issue is that later (after debugger exits my code) I get a crash in B saying:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 10, found: 9
```

The stacktrace starts with:

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)`
```

Not sure what's going on here .. shouldn't the activity B be gone for good after finish was called and before A.onActivityResult() is called?

Is this because the exiting animation requires a final draw from B?

EDIT: B.onStop() and B.onDestroy() are called after A.onActivityResult(). Why is this normal behaviour?

Comment: When you removed one element from the data set do you notifyDataSetChanged? I think that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to call notifyDataSetChanged() before calling getCount() in your adapter.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {

  notifyDataSetChanged();

  return list.size();

}
```